# Angular2 Error token must be defined

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error while using angular-cli.

```
Error: Token must be defined!
    at new ReflectiveKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48893:19) [angular]
    at KeyRegistry.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48946:39) [angular]
    at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48911:35) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:117530:102) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66988:52) [angular]
    at RouterInitializer.appInitializer (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73780:48) [angular]
    at new ApplicationInitStatus (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:46874:45) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:424:36) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66971:76) [angular]
    at NgModuleFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66939:18) [angular]
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47309:61 [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:37314:37) [angular]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the full error message as text.

Comment: Could you provide more information?

Comment: This is the only information which i got from browser and i am not able to run my app. I am using angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

I'm receiving the same error after doing a fresh NPM install from a working project. Check your Package.json file for dependencies with "^" such as zone.js below. Remove the "^" to make npm install the version specified and not a later one.

Then reinstall your node_modules and it should work

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.2",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.2",
"@angular/core": "2.4.2",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.2",
"@angular/http": "2.4.2",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.2",
"@angular/router": "^3.4.2",
"@ngrx/core": "^1.1.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^2.1.2",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.3",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"reselect": "^2.5.4",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.7.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same error and took me an hour to figure out that I had accidentally used wrong variable on TestBed

```
let someService
...
someService= TestBed.get(someService);
```

It should be:

```
someService= TestBed.get(SomeService); <-- with big caps 'S'
```